# Unable to map to share on AWS Ec2 from office, works at home

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've setup an Ec2 instance of Windows server 2016 on AWS.

I can map to a shared drive on this instance from my home (desktop, and laptop) and mobile device. I use domain from home, and IP on mobile.

I bring my laptop to the office and am unable to map to the drive. I have access to RDP still, but no SMB. I believe this is blocked from the ISP.

I tried connecting from home, while connected to a different location on ExpressVPN, and was unable to connect.

The instance hosts software used by the company. There is a DB on the instance and the software on the workstations/endpoints is able to connect to the DB on the instance.

I read I should switch the SMB port to 80. I opened some ports, but still can't connect.

Comment: Are you saying that you can connect to the EC2 share from home, but you cannot do so from the office? If so, check the configuration of the Security Group on the instance, since it might be restricting IP address ranges. If that isn't the case then, yes, it sounds like a restriction within your corporate network. Talk to your IT admins about it. You might have to tether via your phone to get access.

Comment: I'm the 'IT Guy' for a local mechanic. I am in charge of their entire infrastructure. 

I have them setup on Ubiquiti, and tested a direct connection the the ISP modem/router. None of these methods worked. Neither does my home PC when I use ExpressVPN. This appears to be a port that's commonly blocked. 

Reading online, the solution appears to be to change the port that the fileshare uses. I've opened ports on AWS, but still no luck.